# Examples of HTML documentation produced with LaTeX

Tags: htlatex, examples, latex2html

I am considering writing some software documentation in LaTeX to compile to HTML.  I know this is possible with at least two tools (htlatex, latex2html) but have not seen any examples of their output.

Can anyone point me at some (preferably large) examples of online docs created by either?

Comment: you could look at the digital library of mathematical functions (which was converted to html via latexml) http://dlmf.nist.gov/

Answer (score 12):

- [TeX4ht documentation](https://www.kodymirus.cz/tex4ht-doc/tex4ht-doc.html) is created automatically from LaTeX sources using Github Actions.
- Nasser Abbasi's web is [created with tex4ht](http://12000.org/). Some pages are really large.
- I've created [some documents](http://michal-h21.github.io/samples/helpers4ht/textstyle.html) with [responsive design](http://michal-h21.github.io/samples/helpers4ht/fontspec.html)
- [Claudio Rodriguez](http://www.claudiordgz.com/study-series/) has some [documents with extensive JavaScript use](http://claudiordgz.github.io/GoodrichTamassiaGoldwasser/) ([Github with supporting files](https://github.com/claudiordgz/StudySeriesStyles))
- Phillip Lord has some [document with JavaScript syntax highlighting](http://homepages.cs.ncl.ac.uk/phillip.lord/take-wing/take_wing.html)